# Is i+++j always treated as i++ + j?

Tags: c, operators

In the printf statement `i+++j`, is it always treated as `i++ +j`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int i =5,j= 6, z;
    z=i^j;
    printf("%d",i+++j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Postfix increment/decrement have high precedence.

Comment: So many duplicates but they are hard to find as +++ doesn't seem to work as a search term.

Comment: @ShashankKadne: It has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: You originally used the "printf" tag. This has nothing to do with `printf`; it's all about the expression `i+++j`, whether it appears as an argument to `printf` or in any other context.

Comment: @PaulR: Found it; "maximal munch" is a better search term.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`i+++j` is equivalent to `i++ + j`.

This has nothing to do with operator precedence. The `+++` is resolved to `++ +` by the compiler before expressions are parsed.

The C standard defines a sequence of *translation phases*, each using as its input the output of the previous one. `+++` is resolved to `++ +` in phase 3, which decomposes the source into preprocessor tokens. Operator precedence is not considered until phase 7, syntactic and semantic analysis. (The translation phases don't have to be implemented as distinct phases or passes, but the compiler must behave as if they are.)

The rules that says `+++` is resolved to `++ +` and not `+ ++` is what's informally called the "maximal munch rule". It's stated in section 6.4 paragraph 4:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence
>   of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

(Amusingly, the index refers to "maximal munch", but that term isn't mentioned anywhere else in the standard.)

This also implies that `i+++++j`, which *could* be tokenized as the valid expression `i++ + ++j`, is actually `i ++ ++ + j`, which is a syntax error.

Of course the solution, for a programmer, is to add whitespace to make the division into tokens clear: `i++ + j`. (`i+++j` is perfectly clear to the compiler, but `i++ + j` is much clearer to a human reader.)

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.4, paragraph 4. N1570 is a draft of the 2011 ISO C standard. This rule is unchanged from earlier versions of the standard. Translation phases are discussed

Comment: +1 for maximal munch rule (never new that before).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will be parsed as `(i++) + (j)`.

Comment: The "yes" is confusing.

Comment: @R..; Why it is confusing to you?

Comment: @R..: The original title was "Is this output dependant on compiler?"; the first sentence in the body of the question is "... is it always treated as `i++ +j`?". The answers are "no" and "yes", respectively. I've just edited the title, incidentally making "yes" the correct answer to both.

Comment: Who downvoted this single line answer?

Answer (score -2):

Since postfix increment/decrement operator has higher precedence over the addition operator, there is no doubt it would be treated as (i++) + j.
So, it is not a compiler issue, you should rather consider the operator precedence chart.

Also, I would suggest you to put proper spaces between the expressions, it would be beneficial in case you go through your code later on. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: If it is not compiler then who is responsible for parsing the expressions?

Comment: "compiler would not depend on it" - it will. `i++ +j` and `i+ ++j` are parsed differently.

Comment: @haccks yes compiler is responsible and it would depend on the spaces, my answer in the question's context. And I have edited it for clarity purpose.

Comment: It has nothing to do with operator precedence. See my answer.

Comment: [Scaner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner) : This is known as the `maximal munch rule`, or `longest match rule`

Comment: @KeithThompson Why it has nothing to do with operator precedence?

Comment: The C standard defines a sequence of *translation phases* each using as its input the output of the previous one. `+++` is resolved to `++ +` in phase 3, which decomposes the source into preprocessor tokens. Operator precedence is not considered until phase 7, syntactic and semantic analysis. (The translation phases don't have to be implemented as distinct phases or passes, but the compiler must behave as if they are.)